# Postgres RLS policy: Only allow SELECT on row based on existence of foreign relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-level-security

I have the following Postgres tables:

**users**

```
+---------+--------------+
| id (PK) |  full_name   |
+---------+--------------+
| uuid()  | varchar      |
+---------+--------------+
```

**organizations**

```
+---------+---------+
| id (PK) |  name   |
+---------+---------+
| uuid()  | varchar |
+---------+---------+
```

**organization_memberships**

```
+---------+----------------------+--------------+
| id (PK) | organization_id (FK) | user_id (FK) |
+---------+----------------------+--------------+
| uuid()  | uuid()               | uuid()       |
+---------+----------------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to write a Postgres Row-Level Security (RLS) policy.

The policy must enforce that users are only able to `SELECT` from the `organizations` table when there is a corresponding entry in the `organization_memberships` table.

This is what I currently have, but doesn't seem to be working as I would expect. Note the `uid()` method is provided by my DBAAS solution to get the authenticated user's id.

```
ALTER POLICY "User can only Select organizations where they are members" ON public.organizations USING (
  (
    EXISTS (
      SELECT
        orgmembs.user_id,
        orgmembs.organization_id
      FROM
        organization_memberships orgmembs
      WHERE
        (
          (orgmembs.organization_id = organizations.id)
          AND (orgmembs.user_id = uid())
        )
    )
  )
);
```

I've also tried this slightly-different version, but I receive the error, `Error updating policy: missing FROM-clause entry for table "organization"`:

```
ALTER POLICY "User can only Select organizations where they are member" ON public.organizations USING (
  auth.uid() IN (
    SELECT
      user_id
    FROM
      organization_memberships
    WHERE
      organization_memberships.organization_id = organization.id
  )
);
```

Comment: Your policy looks fine. Please describe how it misbehaves. Perhaps the user running the query owns the table or is otherwise exempt from RLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
alter POLICY "User can only Select organizations where they are member"
      ON organizations 
      USING (id  IN (
                        SELECT organization_id 
                        FROM organization_memberships om 
                        JOIN users u ON om.user_id = u.id
                    )
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This doesn't seem to work as-is. Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I did not understand your question correctly. What exactly do you want the policy to be?

Comment: The goal is a user may only select rows from the `organizations` table if there is a corresponding row in `organization_memberships` which contains the `user.id` and the `organization.id`.

Comment: Correct.. The `organization_memberships` table maps `users` to `organizations`. I don't want users to be able to `SELECT` organzations that they don't belong to. Is this behavior not possible? This seems like a common relation pattern

Comment: I edited the code. When requested by the organization, the ones that the user join to organization_memberships are displayed.